# Override Javascript's toString for numbers

Tags: javascript, overriding, tostring

I'm overriding the `toString` method for numbers in javascript, because I need it to return `""` for `NaN` values, instead of the default `"NaN"`:

```
Number.prototype.original_toString = Number.prototype.toString;
Number.prototype.toString = function(radix) {
  var originalValue = this.original_toString(radix);
  if (originalValue == "NaN") {
    return "";
  } else {
    return originalValue;
  }
};
```

Then I get the following behavior:

```
(3).toString()         => "3"
Number.NaN.toString()  => ""
```

That's ok. The problem is when I convert numbers to string the following way:

```
"" + 3            => "3"
"" + Number.NaN   => "NaN"  # This is not what I expected
```

As you can see, in this case the overridden method is not being used. Is there any other way to do this so that it works fine in both cases? I also tried overriding `Number.prototype.toLocaleString` and no luck. Here's a jsfiddle to play around with: http://jsfiddle.net/tmjf8cao/3/

Comment: The `NaN` property is a not writable constant -> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NaN

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that, `Num.NAN` is a static variable(not a "number" belongs to number), which means you havent override its toString() method. You can try to override Number.`NaN.toString` also.

Answer (score 1):

I think maybe the implicit toString method can't be overridden at all.

I.e.

```
Number.prototype.toString = function() { return "hello world!" };

(3).toString()  => "hello world!"
3 + "" => "3"
```

Comment: I think it may be because `3 instanceof Number === false` (on the other hand `new Number(3) instanceof Number === true`, but `typeof new Number(3) !== "number"`)